How to convert Type to C#-parseable string
I'm playing with dynamic code generation in C#, based on some interfaces I have. One of the things I need to do is to match type provided in interface property with generated code. I don't really need to make decisions on it, just match it one-to-one.
I'm compiling from text, not AST, so I need to provide proper C# code as an input. And here the problem starts - while some Type instances can be nicely converted, others have internal string representations, like System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of List<string> (or System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>). Same goes for int? going to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
I can write some translation class covering 1 and 2 argument generics and nullables specifically, but I wonder if maybe there is already a ready to use method for such conversion, either in core library or some open source library?

Please specify more precisely what you have and what you need. I doubt you have something like System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` as input text, because that's not valid C#, it's the IL representation of a type.

For simplicity - typeof(List).ToString() gives System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String], but I would like some method to get "List" string back (or equivalent with full namespace)

Maybe use the Roslyn compiler API?

In a T4 template I was using the following methods to generate a C# type name given a System.Type parameter. Because the code was quite old and did not manage nested types involving generics correctly and was missing newer C# type aliases and value tuples, I revised it to give you a complete answer. It also uses newer C# language features.
I also added an overload accepting a .NET type name as string and an optional Boolean parameter includeNamespace.
public static string? GetCSharpName(string dotNetName, bool includeNamespace = false)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(dotNetName);
    if (type is null) return null;
    return GetCSharpName(type, includeNamespace);
}

public static string GetCSharpName(Type type, bool includeNamespace = false)
{
    string? result = GetPrimitiveType(type);
    if (result != null) return result;

    if (type.IsNested && !type.IsGenericParameter) {
        Type[] arguments = type.IsGenericType ? type.GetGenericArguments() : [];
        Type? t = type;
        int skipLast = 0;
        while (t is not null) {
            string name = RemoveGenericCount(includeNamespace && !t.IsNested ? t.FullName! : t.Name);
            int argumentCount = GenericArgumentCount(t) - GenericArgumentCount(t.DeclaringType);
            if (argumentCount > 0) {
                string argumentString = String.Join(",",
                    arguments
                        .SkipLast(skipLast)
                        .TakeLast(argumentCount)
                        .Select(t => GetCSharpName(t, includeNamespace)));
                name += $"<{argumentString}>";
                skipLast += argumentCount;
            }
            result = result is null ? name : $"{name}.{result}";
            t = t.DeclaringType;
        }
        return result!;
    }

    result = RemoveGenericCount(includeNamespace ? type.FullName! : type.Name);

    if (!type.IsGenericType) return result;
    if (IsNullable(type)) return $"{GetCSharpName(type.GetGenericArguments()[0])}?";

    string typeArguments = String.Join(", ",
        type.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => GetCSharpName(t, includeNamespace)));
    return IsValueTuple(type) ? $"({typeArguments})" : $"{result}<{typeArguments}>";
}

private static string RemoveGenericCount(string typeName)
{
    int index = typeName.IndexOf('`');
    if (index >= 0) {
        return typeName[..index];
    }
    return typeName;
}

private static int GenericArgumentCount(Type? type)
{
    return type?.IsGenericType ?? false ? type.GetGenericArguments().Length : 0;
}

private static bool IsNullable(Type type)
{
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
}

private static bool IsValueTuple(Type type)
{
    Type genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    return type.IsGenericType && (
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>) ||
            genericType == typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>)
        );
}

private static string? GetPrimitiveType(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsArray) {
        string? name = GetPrimitiveType(t.GetElementType()!);
        int index = t.FullName!.IndexOf('[');
        return $"{name}{t.FullName[index..]}";
    }
    return t.FullName switch {
        "System.Boolean" => "bool",
        "System.Byte" => "byte",
        "System.Char" => "char",
        "System.Decimal" => "decimal",
        "System.Double" => "double",
        "System.Single" => "float",
        "System.Int32" => "int",
        "System.Int64" => "long",
        "System.SByte" => "sbyte",
        "System.Int16" => "short",
        "System.String" => "string",
        "System.UInt32" => "uint",
        "System.UInt64" => "ulong",
        "System.UInt16" => "ushort",
        "System.Object" => "object",
        "System.IntPtr" => "nint",
        "System.UIntPtr" => "nuint",
        _ => null
    };
}

My test setup declares the following type:
public class Parent<T>
{
    public class Nested
    {
        public class NestedTwice<U> { }
    }
}

The difficulty here is that the most nested type inherits all the type parameters of its declaring types. Therefore, my first naive approach resulted in "Parent<int>.Nested<int>.NestedTwice<int,string>", but we want "Parent<int>.Nested.NestedTwice<string>".
Console Test:
string[] examples = [
    "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]",
    "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]",
    "System.Int32[]",
    "System.Single[,]",
    "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]]",
    "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection+Enumerator[[System.Int32],[System.String]]",
    typeof(Parent<int>.Nested.NestedTwice<string>).FullName!,
    typeof((string, int, List<(bool, DateTime)>)).FullName!,
];
foreach (string example in examples) {
    Console.WriteLine(GetCSharpName(example));
}
Console.ReadKey();

Result:
List<string>
int?
int[]
float[,]
Dictionary<int, List<string>>
Dictionary<int,string>.ValueCollection.Enumerator
Parent<int>.Nested.NestedTwice<string>
(string, int, List<(bool, DateTime)>)


Here's my implementation:
// CC BY-SA 4.0

using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Provides methods to encode and decode C# types to and from strings using reflection.
/// </summary>
public static class CSharpReflectionParsableString
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> s_csharpKeywords =
    [
        "string", "char", "bool", "byte", "sbyte", "short", "ushort", "int", "uint",
        "long", "ulong", "float", "double", "decimal", "object"
    ];

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> s_csharpKeywordToTypeMapping = new()
    {
        { "string", typeof(string) },
        { "char", typeof(char) },
        { "bool", typeof(bool) },
        { "byte", typeof(byte) },
        { "sbyte", typeof(sbyte) },
        { "short", typeof(short) },
        { "ushort", typeof(ushort) },
        { "int", typeof(int) },
        { "uint", typeof(uint) },
        { "long", typeof(long) },
        { "ulong", typeof(ulong) },
        { "float", typeof(float) },
        { "double", typeof(double) },
        { "decimal", typeof(decimal) },
        { "object", typeof(object) }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Decodes a string representation of a type to its corresponding <see cref="Type"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parsableString">The string representation of the type.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceAssembly">The assembly to search for the type.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Type"/> object if found; otherwise, null.</returns>
    public static Type? Decode(string parsableString, Assembly sourceAssembly)
    {
        if (parsableString.Contains('<'))
        {
            // If we reach here, we know that the type
            // in question is generic and requires a
            // bit more logic.

            return DecodeGeneric(parsableString, sourceAssembly);
        }
        else if (s_csharpKeywords.Contains(parsableString))
        {
            // For example, bool, ushort, etc.
            return s_csharpKeywordToTypeMapping[parsableString];
        }
        else
        {
            // Reaching here means a non-generic type, for example,
            // System.Random.
            return sourceAssembly.GetType(parsableString);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes a <see cref="Type"/> object to its string representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to encode.</param>
    /// <returns>The string representation of the type.</returns>
    public static string Encode(Type type)
    {
        if (type.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
        {
            // Reaching here means that the type contains generic parameters.
            string fullName = type.FullName!;
            fullName = fullName[..fullName.IndexOf('`')];

            return $"{fullName}<{string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(argument => argument.Name))}>";
        }
        else if (s_csharpKeywordToTypeMapping.ContainsValue(type))
        {
            // Reaching here means a built-in (a.k.a. primitive) type.
            return s_csharpKeywordToTypeMapping.ToArray().First(kvp => kvp.Value == type).Key;
        }
        else
        {
            // Reaching here means a non-generic type.
            if (type.Namespace is not null)
            {
                return $"{type.Namespace}.{type.Name}";
            }
            return $"{type.Name}";
        }
    }

    private static Type? DecodeGeneric(string parsableString, Assembly sourceAssembly)
    {
        string nonGenericPart = parsableString[..parsableString.IndexOf('<')];
        // ^^^
        // Example: "System.Collections.Generic.List<T> -> System.Collections.Generic"

        string genericPart = parsableString[(parsableString.IndexOf('<') + 1)..];
        genericPart = genericPart[.. genericPart.IndexOf('>')];

        // ^^^
        // Example: "...Dictionary<TKey, TValue>" -> "<TKey, TValue>"

        int numberOfGenericParameters = genericPart.Contains(',')
                                        ? genericPart.Split(',').Length
                                        : 1;
        // ^^^
        // Amount of generic parameters, f.e. <T> is 1 and <T1, T2, T3> is 3.

        nonGenericPart = $"{nonGenericPart}`{numberOfGenericParameters}";

        return sourceAssembly.GetTypes()
                             .FirstOrDefault(type => type.FullName == nonGenericPart);
    }
}

Examples:
using CSharpParseableString;
using System.Reflection;

Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(bool)));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(char)));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(string)));

Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(List<>)));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(Dictionary<,>)));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Encode(typeof(BigGeneric<,,,,>)));

Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Assembly corLib = typeof(string).Assembly;

Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("bool", thisAssembly));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("char", thisAssembly));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("string", thisAssembly));

Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("System.Collections.Generic.List<T>", corLib));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>", corLib));
Console.WriteLine(CSharpReflectionParsableString.Decode("BigGeneric<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>", thisAssembly));

struct BigGeneric<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
{
}

Output:
bool
char
string
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
BigGeneric<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
System.Boolean
System.Char
System.String
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
BigGeneric`5[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5]

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHYRln
